# Создание авторегера vk.com на python с помощью requests

Tags: python, вконтакте, requests

Подтверждение смс кода:

```
url3='https://api.vk.com/method/auth.validatePhoneConfirm?'

headers1={
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'ru,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'content-length': '368',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'cookie': COOKIE,
    'origin': 'https://id.vk.com',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'referer': 'https://id.vk.com/',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Yandex";v="22"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.141 YaBrowser/22.3.2.644 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36',
}


data1={
    'sid': SID1,
    'phone': NUMBER,
    'code': SMS,
    'auth_token': TOKEN,
    'service_group': '',
    'can_skip_password': '1',
    'access_token': "",
}

ch1=vk_site.post(url3,headers=headers1,data=data1)
```

Есть код который запускает отправку смс кода на выбранный телефон, там все работает нормально, но с частью подтверждения смс кода что-то явно не так, пока не могу понять что.

Тут как я понимаю ему не нравится значение access_token, хотя я его правильно записал, может проблема в чем-то другом?

[image: Название ошибки]

Вот data на самом сайте:

[image: Data с запроса на сайте]

Headers запроса на сайте:

[image: Заголовки запросов]

**UPD:**
Теперь следующая проблема, остался последний этап регистрации, а именно - ввод имени, фамилии, пароля и даты рождения, он просит service_token, насколько я понял это токен приложения вк, токен приложения есть, но ошибка не исчезла

[image: Ошибка]

Часть кода:

[image: Код]

Пока что не ясно как конкретно использовать его...

Comment: Я думаю, что токен доступа постоянно изменяется, а значит вы не можете просто скопировать токен из браузера в свой код. Нужно искать способ получить этот  токен прямо из вашего кода

Comment: Простите, но вы уверены что auth_token и access_token одно и тоже? он ругается на access_token, а передаете вы только auth_token (при этом в браузере передаются ОБА токена)

Comment: я и не считал что это одно и то же, access_token в data ничему не равен и появляется только в следующем запросе, поэтому я сделал вывод что он, вероятно, еще не сгенерировался

Comment: Только что проверил, access_token генерируется при завершении регистрации, до этого его нигде нет

Comment: этот проект есть на гитхабе? Я сейчас ищу готовый авторег. Если поделишься, то буду очень благодарен!!

Answer (score 1):

Как и сказал человек выше, несмотря на то что в запросе значение access_token является пустым, его всё равно необходимо узнать и передать, я нашел место где он генерируется и передал его, все работает